# How can I extract some patterns of sub text from a gibberish looking text using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, match

I have some text where the age and gender of a person is mentioned in some of the records (not all) as `28M`, or `35 F`, or `29 male`, or `57Female`, etc.

I wrote the following regular expression to check if there is any pattern that matches a number followed by a `M` in an input string, and if yes to print it out, but the code does not print anything:

```
import re

text = 'Decision: Standard\r\n\r\n 36M NS\r\nBasic - 500th MP tdb addd cib 250th\r\n\r\nDue Date: Settlement date'

test_search = re.search('[0-9]+M', text)

if test_search:
    print("Age: "+test_search.group(0)+", Gender: "+test_search.group(1))
```

I expected it to have printed `Age: 36, Gender: M`. However, it does nothing - no error, no output, nothing.

I tried `re.match('[0-9]+F', text)`, nothing happened there either.

Also, I thought I have to write as many regular expressions as there are patterns (one each for `28M`, `35 F`, `29Male`, `57 female`, etc). Is that the correct approach? Or is there a way to search/find/match all of these patterns at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex to match all the cases you have mentioned in question:

```
results = re.findall(r'(?i)(\d+)\s*([mf]|(?:fe)?male)\b', text)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xepdys/1)

**Details:**

- `(?i)`: Ignore case modifier
- `(\d+)`: Match and capture 1+ digits in group #1
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `([mf]|(?:fe)?male)`: Match or capture `M` or `F` or `male` or `female` in group #2
- `\b`: word boundary

Comment: Great! I am kinda new to regular expressions, and find them clunky. If you could kindly explain why my code was not working, that would be awesome!

Comment: I have added regex details in answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`this regex`](https://regex101.com/r/D2MjI3/1) 
`([0-9]+)\s?([M|Male|F|Female]+)` and capture the age and name in seperate capturing groups.

**[`Python Demo`](https://repl.it/repls/UnrulyDullSorting)**

```
import re

test_str = r"Decision: Standard\\r\\n\\r\\n 36M NS\\r\\nBasic - 500th MP tdb addd cib 250th\\r\\n\\r\\nDue Date: Settlement date 29 male 57Female 35 F"

pattern = r"([0-9]+)\s?([M|Male|F|Female]+)"

def return_gender_dict(match_obj):
    return { 'age': match_obj[0], 'gender': match_obj[1][0].upper() }

matches = re.findall(pattern, test_str, flags=re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

result = [return_gender_dict(match) for match in matches]

print(result)
```

Outputting:

```
[{'age': '36', 'gender': 'M'}, {'age': '29', 'gender': 'M'}, {'age': '57', 'gender': 'F'}, {'age': '35', 'gender': 'F'}]
```

Comment: For texts like the following `test_str = "decision: standard, age: 30/f/NS rate, basic: standard (maxilink prime 500k (X2=1M), adb: standard (ps 500k), tdb: standard (ps 500k), cib: standard (ps 1M), due date: settlement date"`, it does not return the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following re

```
(\d\d)(M|F|Male|Female|\sM|\sF|\sMale|\sFemale)
```